# Update node from comment form

Tags: comments

Is there a way in drupal 7 where you can change a value of a field from the comment form of that node you are commenting on? At the moment I have a comment form within a node which has the same field as that node. When I change that value, it does not update the nodes field but only changes the comment form's field.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a module to do this, you can probably modify it to suit your needs. http://drupal.org/sandbox/jrowny/1281972 I was using this for 'casetracker' type functionality.

Basically you install this and check for each field "this field is editable by comments."

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. 

Ill try this module out now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Please accept the response. In the future people will be happy to answer questions for you if they see you have a high acceptance rate.

Comment: Okay will do in future (Green tick under the vote down arrow?)