# Which function should I use to update a node through the comment form?

Tags: comments

I use this function to synchronize a comment field with the value from a field that exists in the node the comment belongs to.

```
function mymodule_comment_create(\Drupal\comment\CommentInterface $comment) {
  $node = $comment->getCommentedEntity();
  if ($node && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if ($node->hasField('field_example')) {
      $comment->subject->value = $node->field_example->value;
    }
  }
}
```

How could I achieve the opposite? When a comment is submitted with the field *field_rating*, the *field_average_rating* field of the node should be updated.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: kiamlaluno my question is for drupal 8 only. There is already a solution and a sandbox module for what I am asking for drupal 7 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15436/update-node-from-comment-form but that does not work in drupal 8. Could you please add back the number of the version in the title so there is no confusion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the same hook hook_comment_create() but just inverse the assignment you do on the comment as in your code, for example:

```
function mymodule_comment_create(\Drupal\comment\CommentInterface $comment) {
  $node = $comment->getCommentedEntity();
  if ($node && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if ($node->hasField('node_field') && $comment->hasField('comment_field') && !empty($comment->comment_field->value)) {
      $node->node_field->value = $comment->comment_field->value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you adrum99 but I just tried that and nothing happened. The Value of the node field did not change... Here is my code            `function hello_comment_create(\Drupal\comment\CommentInterface $comment) {
  $node = $comment->getCommentedEntity();
  if ($node && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    if ($node->hasField('field_nod') && $comment->hasField('field_com') && !empty($comment->field_com->value)) {
      $node->field_nod->value = $comment->field_com->value;
    }
  }
}`